# American English pronunciation dictionary in text form showing syllables

Tags: data-request, language

Looking for pronunciation and syllabification data for American English.  I want to analyze pronunciation and spelling rules/heuristics to see how accurate they are and identify exceptions.  The goal is to help English as a Second Language students.  Rule example: most English words have the accent on the second-to-last syllable.

If it's useful I would make it available to others.  No commercial ambitions for now.

The CMU Pronouncing Dictionary (http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict) has 133K pronunciation entries but without syllabification.

I plan to use data from http://www.wordfrequency.info/ to limit the analysis to the most frequent words (20K?  30K?).

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with wiktionary.org?

Comment: ... or http://www.dictionaryapi.com/

Comment: Not all words in wiktionary.org have pronunciations.  Trying less than 10 words, I found that "precision" and "tesseract" don't have pronunciations.  dictionary.api.com is a good idea, I'm looking into it.